# Why the index.html of my React build is blank?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, snowpack

I am making a React app using Snowpack. Everything works correctly, the build is also successful. But when I am tying to open the index.html of the build, the page is blank.

I have found a temporary fix, by modifying the index.html from the build folder.

Original index.html build code (Blank page):

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>React page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="/js/webpack-runtime.0ec3dfa59e6510ed107b.js"></script><script src="/js/lib-react-dom.743af248c46307798cb8.js"></script><script src="/js/index.6929e3680f85299b6d65.js"></script>

</body></html>
```

and here is the modified one that is working:

```
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>React page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="./js/webpack-runtime.0ec3dfa59e6510ed107b.js"></script><script src="./js/lib-react-dom.743af248c46307798cb8.js"></script><script src="./js/index.6929e3680f85299b6d65.js"></script>

</body></html>
```

The trick is to replace `src=/js/xxxxx.js` to `src=./js/xxxxx.js`

The problem is that is very annoying to modify each time you build the project so is there any way to fix this ?

Here is my `snowpack.config.js` code:

```
module.exports = {
    devOptions: {
        port: 3000
    },

    mount: {
        src: "/dist",
        public: {url: "/", static: true}
    },

    plugins: [
        [
            '@snowpack/plugin-webpack', {
                htmlMinifierOptions: false
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

and the script tag of my index.html:

```
<script src="./dist/index.js" type="module"></script>
```

Thanks in advance for the help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are pointing the public scripts load URL to be at the root of your computer, not the place that your scripts have been put!

I think if you change your `mount.public` to this:

```
public: {url: "./", static: true}
```

It should work correctly!